# Problems extruding face mask loop

Tags: objects

My daughter is extruding but all these extra lines form.

Bottom section and top center of image shows extra lines
[image: bottom section and top center of image shows extra lines]

We are total newbies. Why do they form?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Rather than take photos of your monitor post actual screenshots instead. See [How to take a screenshot](https://www.take-a-screenshot.org), so we don't have to guess if we are looking at a external interference like reflections or smudges, a hardware issue such as a malfunctioning display or connection, a software level bug or driver, or an or actual artifact or issue with the model itself.